Flutter - Sending POST request with 307 error
So this is my first time messing around with REST API. My goal is to automate phone calls using a 3rd party website (robotalker.com) for my company. I'm sending a POST request and keep getting a '307 Temporary Redirect Error.' The server then sends back the exact same url that I am using as the 'Temporary Redirect' location. Any insight would be super helpful.
your text
try {
    final uri = Uri.parse('https://robotalker.com/REST/api/MultiJob');
    const username = 'username';
    const token = 'token';
    final body = {
        "var1": "val"
        ....
    };

    var credentials = base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$token'));

    final headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic $credentials',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    };

    http.Response response = await http.post(
        uri,
        headers: headers,
        body: jsonEncode(body),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) { 
        print('Response: ${response.body}');
    } else if (response.statusCode == 307) {
        print(
            '${response.statusCode}\n${response.reasonPhrase}\n${response.headers}\nBody: $             {response.body}');
    } else {
        print(
            'Failed to connect: ${response.statusCode}, ${response.reasonPhrase}, ${response.headers}');
    }
  
} catch (e) {
    print('An error occurred: $e');
}

And this is the output:
Response code: 307
Response Phrase: Temporary Redirect
Response Headers: {set-cookie: .ASPXAUTH= 'some hex string'; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax, cache-control: no-cache, access-control-allow-origin: *, date: Sun, 21 Apr 2024 19:35:37 GMT, pragma: no-cache, server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0, x-powered-by: ASP.NET, access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, location: https://robotalker.com/REST/api/MultiJob, access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, content-length: 0, x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319, expires: -1}
As you can see the Location in the Response Headers is the exact same as the url request.
